# How to save a Date as text to Websql in format dd/mmm/yyyy?

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-sql

I am updating an old app where I take in a date (DOB) and (currently) save it as text to a websql database. I am aware websql is not really used anymore but at this time I don't want to re-do the whole app. 
e.g.

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
                           tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, name TEXT, surname TEXT, added_on DATETIME, note TEXT, dob TEXT, gender TEXT, )", []);
```

and

```
var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
```

This is currently saving the DOB as dd/mm/yy which makes it difficult for the US users as a date can display as 05/06/10.
I want this to display as 05 June 2010 (the month spelled out) instead. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to parse the date value in order to do this:

```js
var value = "05/06/2010".split("/"); //please note that you'll need to use four digits as a year for years in 2000. Two digit years refer to years from 1900 till 1999.
//Split the date into parts using the /.

//Use a month array to display the correct month as text
var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September", "October","November", "December"];

//Feed the date as year, month-1, day else we will get ackward results.
var date = new Date(value[2], value[1]-1, value[0]); //subtract 1 from the month since it's zero indexed.
document.body.innerHTML += date.getDate() + " " + months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear(); //rewrite the string

//In modern browsers (IE11, firefox and Chrome) you can use toLocaleString() option

document.body.innerHTML += "<br />";
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
document.body.innerHTML += date.toLocaleString('en-UK',options);
```

Comment: I found this... http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
Does this mean I can do this:

dob DATETIME ( dob, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')